# How to custom date return by google ajax api feed service with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

In my angularjs controller i have this :

```
Feed.parseFeed("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=618857251494402&format=rss20").then(function(res){
    $scope.feeds1=res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
$scope.quantity1 = 5;
});
```

this is the factory :

```
app.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        parseFeed : function(url) {
            return $http.jsonp('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url), {cache: false})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                }).error(function(status) {
                    console.log(status);
                });
        }
    }
}]);
```

and html :

```
                <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds1">                    
                    <p>
                        <span>{{feed.publishedDate | date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm'}}</span> 
                        <a href="{{feed.link}}" ng-click="createTab(feed.link);">{{feed.title}}</a>
                    </p>                                        
                </li>
```

Problem is with this code i have date like "Wed, 13 Aug 2014 12:31:01 -0700", it's the original date parsed with google api, so nothing is changed here. How to format it ?

Comment: By format it you mean what exactly?

Comment: change the format, for use as indicated in the filter

Comment: There is momentjs which is a popular third party library for doing stuff with dates. There isn't anything built in (like there is in c# for instance). I think your choices are going to be roll your own formatting function or find a third party script.